# ratio test with $\lim \sup $

Tags: solution-verification, absolute-convergence

Is there any flaw in following proof

> **Theorem** : consider a bounded sequence $(a_n)$ and let $s_k = \sup \{|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| : n \geq k\}$ and $l = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} s_k$   $\,\,\,\,$  if    $l < 1$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ absolutely converges

*proof*

- since consider $l'$ st $0<l<l'<1$
- now fix $\epsilon = |l'-l|$
- we know that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \, , \, \forall n  \geq N \,\,\bigg| s_{n} - l \bigg| < \epsilon $ which implies $ s_{n} < l'$
- fix at $N$ from which we have that $s_{N} < l' \implies |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| < l' \,\,\, \forall  n \geq N$
- $|a_{n+1}| < l'|a_{n}| \,\,\, \forall  n \geq N$ from which we have that $a_{m} < (l')^{m-N}|a_{N}|$  $\,\,\,\forall m > N$
- $\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} |a_{n}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (l')^k |a_{N}| = |a_{N}| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (l')^k  < \infty$
- hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|$ absolutely converges

Comment: And since you didn't use in your proof that $(a_n)$ is bounded, then it is not needed as a hypothesis in the theorem. It is actually a property that can be derived from the other hypotheses.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy can you write answer so that I can accept